# Can't deploy a simple Flask application on Webfaction

Tags: python, flask, webfaction

I have been trying to get Flask to work on my webfaction server for hours with no results.

I followed the instructions at http://flask.pocoo.org/snippets/65/

I have my index.py file stored under htdocs.

```
import sys
yourappname = "/home/<myusername>/webapps/myapp/htdocs"
if not yourappname in sys.path:
    sys.path.insert(0, yourappname)

from yourappname import app as application
```

Then I have added this to my httpd.conf file:

```
WSGIPythonPath /home/yourusername/webapps/yourapp/htdocs/
#If you do not specify the following directive the app *will* work but you will
#see index.py in the path of all URLs
WSGIScriptAlias / /home/yourusername/webapps/yourapp/htdocs/index.py

<Directory /home/yourusername/webapps/yourapp/htdocs/>
   AddHandler wsgi-script .py
   RewriteEngine on
   RewriteBase /
   WSGIScriptReloading On
</Directory>
```

then i have myapp.py in the same htdocs directory next to index.py:

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def hello_world():
    return 'Hello World!'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

I have my domain pointed to my project in webfaction.  The default index.py was working prior to me overwriting with the new one as stated in the instructions.  However, I only get the server 500.  I apologize but I am a complete noob when it comes to linux and managing servers.  I cannot even access my error log under users because it says I do not have permission.

I think that it has something to do with my installation of flask on the linux server, i installed it through easy install it says it installed all of the dependencies and did not give any errors.

Comment: You should really consider using the daemon mode of mod_wsgi instead of the embedded interpreter. There is also no good reason to put any of your python code inside your document root.

Comment: thank you, I will research daemon mode of mod_wsgi.  I will also move my python code out of the document root.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of suggestions:

1. Shouldn't you have myapp everywhere you have yourappname in your index.py?
2. Also, I am assuming that you have made the appropriate substitutions in `WSGIPythonPath /home/yourusername/webapps/yourapp/htdocs
3. Have you tried restarting the apache server by issuing a `~/webapps/<app_name>/apache2/bin/restart`