# Deploying a simple flask app on web faction

Tags: python, flask, mod-wsgi, webfaction

I have set up a sample testapp as described in "[Can't deploy a simple Flask application on Webfaction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10156591/cant-deploy-a-simple-flask-application-on-webfaction)" to get a basic webapp running.

Below is the code snippet and structure :

"On web faction server"

```
/home/<user>/webapps
ls
>> testapp ( <-- my testapp)
    cd testapp
    >> apache2 htdocs
    cd htdocs
    >> index.py testapp.py
```

my index.py file stored under htdocs is as below :

```
import sys
testapp = "/home/<user>/webapps/testapp/htdocs"
if not testapp in sys.path:
    sys.path.insert(0, testapp)
from testapp import app as application
```

my testapp.py file stored under htdocs is as below :

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)
@app.route('/')            
def hello_world():
    return 'Hello World!'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

My httpd.conf stored under /home//webapps/testapp/apache2/conf is as below :

```
ServerRoot "/home/<user>/webapps/testapp/apache2"
LoadModule dir_module        modules/mod_dir.so
LoadModule env_module        modules/mod_env.so
LoadModule log_config_module modules/mod_log_config.so
LoadModule mime_module       modules/mod_mime.so
LoadModule rewrite_module    modules/mod_rewrite.so
LoadModule setenvif_module   modules/mod_setenvif.so
LoadModule wsgi_module       modules/mod_wsgi.so
LogFormat "%{X-Forwarded-For}i %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-    Agent}i\"" combined
CustomLog /home/<user>/logs/user/access_testapp.log combined
DirectoryIndex index.py
DocumentRoot /home/<user>/webapps/testapp/htdocs
ErrorLog /home/<user>/logs/user/error_testapp.log
KeepAlive Off
Listen 24329
MaxSpareThreads 3
MinSpareThreads 1
ServerLimit 1
SetEnvIf X-Forwarded-SSL on HTTPS=1
ThreadsPerChild 5
WSGIDaemonProcess testapp processes=5 python-path=/home/<user>/webapps/testapp       /lib/python3.1 threads=1
WSGIProcessGroup testapp
WSGIRestrictEmbedded On
WSGILazyInitialization On
WSGIPythonPath /home/<user>/webapps/testapp/htdocs
WSGIScriptAlias / /home/<user>/webapps/testapp/htdocs/index.py
<Directory /home/<user>/webapps/testapp/htdocs>
    AddHandler wsgi-script .py
    ReWriteEngine  on
    RewriteBase /
    WSGIScriptReloading On   
</Directory>
```

I have my domain pointed to my project in webfaction. The default index.py was working prior to me overwriting with the new one as stated in the instructions.

Below are the details of my application in the control panel section on web faction :

```
testapp
Name    testapp
Label   mod_wsgi 3.4/Python 3.2
Machine     
Web377
Description     
mod_wsgi 3.4/Python 3.2
Port    24329
```

I have check the error_testapp.log under user's and see below :

```
[Mon Feb 04 07:45:05 2013] [notice] caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Mon Feb 04 07:45:10 2013] [notice] Apache/2.2.17 (Unix) mod_wsgi/3.4 Python/3.2.3 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Mon Feb 04 07:57:14 2013] [notice] caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Mon Feb 04 07:57:19 2013] [notice] Apache/2.2.17 (Unix) mod_wsgi/3.4 Python/3.2.3 configured -- resuming normal operations
```

On trying to launch the app from http:// <user>.webfactional.com/testapp/

I get "Site not Configured" message.

Can someone please shed light on what may be going wrong here.This is my first time with Flask and webfaction.Thanks in advance for your time.Please let me know if you need more details.

Answer (score 0):

[Flask does not support Python 3 currently](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/advanced_foreword/#the-status-of-python-3) - you'll need to switch back to Python 2.7.3 (or look at CherryPy or Pyramid, as both of those frameworks support Python 3).